How to lay robot mower boundary wire for 2 separate mowers?
I have 2 different robot mowers, one to cut the backyard, and one to cut the front yard.  The 'zones', backyard, and front yard are connected.
Mower A picks up the mower B's boundary wire sometimes, and other times, it does not.  Mower B only picks up its boundary wire (they're different brands).
I originally had the wire on top of one another, but mower A went right through the perimeter.  I then tried a Venn diagram with mower A's zone going into mower B's zone by about 1-ft, then 3-ft, and finally about 4-ft.  It still ended up staying in mower B's zone.
What are my options?  I want to avoid separating the 2 'zones' with an area I have to manually cut, that seems to defeat the purpose of having a robot mower in the first place.  I have the option to re-run mower B wire in a continuous loop, about 800-ft around the perimeter of the yard which is about 1/2 acre after subtracting out space for the house, driveway, garden, and trees.  I also want to avoid that as that will be about 2 hours of effort to lay and about another 2 hours of effort to remove the old boundary wire.  I have already laid the entire yard twice as I made adjustments to positioning of the wire based on where the mowers were getting stuck.
Before I do that though, are there any minor tweaks I can try?

what did the manufacturer's technical support say?

The less-than-ideal solution of keeping the boundary wires about 4-ft apart which would result in me having an area I need to manually mow.


You mixed vendors? These are from 2 different autonomous lawn mower OEMs?? 2) You have not described to us the technology used by the OEM to detect the proximity of the autonomous mower to the wire. We would only be guessing at a solutions. What would I do? I'd junk the wire approach and invest in a precision (down to the inch) GPS system. Warning: This requires a local GPS base station that transmits correction data to the GPS receivers on each lawn mower. And will likely cost hundreds of dollars to implement.


Yes, 1 manufacturer stopped selling in the US.  Yes, that is one solution, albeit, a very expensive one.  It'd be at least 3 times as expensive.

I posted a solution but deleted it for safety reasons (more people than you and I read these things). If your mowers are safe, will not harm people because they have no blades (use plastic filament), you might consider what would happen if you alternated between powering up one boundary radio then the other. But not both at the same time. Maybe your mowers will stay inside their boundary areas or maybe not stay inside their boundary areas. The assumption is that one of the transmitters is interfering with the other in the case of the mower that currently not behaving as expected.
